# TypeScript compiler allows calling non-existing getter. Is this a bug in the compiler?

Tags: typescript, encapsulation

In short, I am very confused why this code compiles without error:

```
class Foobar {
    #data = 0
    set data(val: number) { this.#data = val }
    // (Notice there is no getter for "data")
}
let foobar = new Foobar()
// Call the setter for data, no problemo
foobar.data = 123
// Call the getter for data, compiler should not allow this imo
console.log(foobar.data) // Prints "undefined"
```

1. Is this a bug in the typescript compiler? I can't find anywhere that this issue is mentioned. Or is my example working as intended (did I miss something?).
2. Is there some way (using eslint rules or tsc) to catch this erroneous code?

Comment: I don't think TypeScript supports write-only properties at the moment. There's an open feature request for it: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21759

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [related but not exactly the same issue in TypeScript github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21980) and the answer is that this is the defined ES6 class behavior.

There is a [linter rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/accessor-pairs) to check that you have a setter without getter or setter without getter.
I don't know if there is any rule that checks for calling a getter that doesn't exist. But you can define a getter that throws an Error, so at least in runtime you will see errors and unit tests would fail.

Comment: Awesome! I will use this linter rule in all my projects from now on. If I call a getter that doesn't exist where setter doesnt exist (either), the compiler complains. So that won't be a problem.